# Transform collection to replace only some values

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-5.5

I am implementing an export function in an app I have built.

The export process fetches a collection of model values and then exports this into a spreadsheet that is downloaded to the client.

On my model, I have both a `user_id` and a `responsibility`. Both of these fields contain an ID that maps back to my users table (usually to two different users).

During the export process, I want to replace the `user_id` and `responsibility` values with the actual users' names, as opposed to their user IDs.

`map()` and `transform()` seem to be the right methods to achieve what I am after, however I can't see an elegant way to achieve what I want.

This is what I have so far:

```
$forms = Form::where('created_at', '>=', (new Carbon('first day of last month'))->toDateString())
                        ->where('created_at', '<=', (new Carbon('last day of last month'))->toDateString())
                        ->get();

$forms->transform(function($form) {
    return [
        'responsibility' => is_null($form->responsibility) ? $form->responsibility : $form->personResponsible->name,
        'user_id' => $form->user->name
    ];
});
```

However, this only returns `responsibility` and `user_id` in the collection - as opposed to just updating these values.

Now, I could just include the rest of the columns in the return array, but that seems unnecessary - surely there is a better way to do this.

**How can I replace two of the values in my model collection with the users' names most efficiently?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just modify the valules you want to transform and return the $form Model:

```
    $forms->transform(function($form) {
        $form->responsibility = is_null($form->responsibility) ? $form->responsibility : $form->personResponsible->name;
        $form->user_id = $form->user->name;
        return $form;
    });
```

Comment: It seems so simple now that you put it like that!